# Export Google WorkSheet as HTML using Service Account Key and its Client

Tags: python, html, google-sheets-api, gspread, pygsheets

I want the download worksheet from Google Sheet as HTML file using **Service Account Key**. **I don't have OAuth Key.**

What all access I have :

1. I have full access of that Particular Google Sheet only.
2. I have shared that Sheet with Service Account Client Email id.

Currently I am using python gspread lib authorizing using "Service Account Key" as I have already shared the Sheet with Service account Client email.
I want to achieve this using python or any other way using code.

Comment: Ok. What's the issue?

Comment: There is no issue. I am not able to find the way to achieve this task.

Comment: What have you tried? What has your research turned up? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have tried using python gspread library.

Comment: What have you tried? You've made it clear that you imported gspread, but what did you actually *do* with it? And how did or did not that work out? You don't show **any** research or effort in your question...